# Well-posed vs. well posed

Tags: grammar, word-usage, hyphenation

I have a question that comes up when writing mathematical problems.

Which of the following is correct:

> The problem is well-posed

or

> The problem is well posed.

I am sure the second is correct. However the first is used in all sorts of papers, books and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen means that the two words are acting as a unit. In other words, it is a choice between whether or not `well` is describing the word `posed`. If it is, then don't use a hyphen. Otherwise, put the hyphen.

There is no reason to use a hyphen because it is clear that `well` is describing `posed`--how is the problem posed? Well. Therefore, you should not use a hyphen.